# Oracle, create index with partition by range

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create an index with partition by date range, the one im using has an error when I run?

```
  CREATE INDEX "PV_TNPM"."TEJAS_SDH_PM_PDH_IDX2" ON "PV_TNPM"."TEJAS_SDH_PM_PDH" ("DATETIME","NODE_NAME", "NODE_IP", "OBJECT_NAME")
 GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE(DATETIME) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
(PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2014-10-10') );
```

But getting an error:

```
Error starting at line : 11 in command -
CREATE INDEX "PV_TNPM"."TEJAS_SDH_PM_PDH_IDX2" ON "PV_TNPM"."TEJAS_SDH_PM_PDH"     ("DATETIME","NODE_NAME", "NODE_IP", "OBJECT_NAME")
GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE(DATETIME) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '15' MINUTE)
(PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2014-10-10') )
Error at Command Line : 12 Column : 37
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Using oracle sql developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interval Partitioning is not supported for index in oracle 11g where this feature was introduced

Please note that Interval is not a valid clause for CREATE INDEX and it is valid for CREATE TABLE

[INTERVAL CLAUSE IN CREATE TABLE 11G R2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#BABJDACD)

[GLOBAL PARTITION CLAUSE IN CREATE INDEX 11G R2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5012.htm#i2150212)